# Writing a csv from a python list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I have a List like this

```
lis = [('a', [('happy:units:1', 'cloud:1'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:2'), 'rating:3']),]
```

I want a csv like this
[image]

```
 import csv

 with open('Yo456!.csv', 'wb') as out:
     csv_out = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
     csv_out.writerow(['id', 'happy:units', 'cloud', 'sad:units', 'rain', 'rating'])
     for row in lis:
         csv_out.writerow(row)
```

But Im getting the OutPut

[image]

Comment: This is because your source list contains only two columns. The second column in turn contain another list/tuple. You need to create a new list which extracts the contents from the nested tuple and then write this new list to csv.

Comment: Why is your data in this format? Is this the output of something?

Comment: yes its the output of one list

Comment: Did you manage to get the flatten code or do you still need an answer?

Comment: I could not flatten the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to flatten the row and iterate it over the row to get the CSV in the required format.Assuming your data will always be in the given format.

```
    lis = [('a', [('happy:units:1', 'cloud:1'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:2'), 'rating:3']),]
    return_list = list()
    # For the sake of simplicity, Im taking the first element of the given list
    for item in lis[0]:
      # Check if the item is a list
      if type(item) is list:
        for it in item:
          # Iterate over the list item to flatten
          if type(it) is tuple:
            for x in it:
              return_list.append(x[x.rfind(':')+1:])
          else:
            return_list.append(it[it.rfind(':')+1:])
       else:
         # If it is not a list then simply append the value
         return_list.append(item)
    print(return_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a function to extract the values from your data.

   ```
   def flatten_row(row):
       """
       Transform a row in my weird format into a flat tuple of values.

       >>> ('a', [('happy:units:1', 'cloud:1'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:2'), 'rating:3'])
       ('a', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3')
       """
       pass  # YOUR CODE HERE
   ```
2. Use your function for fame and profit

   ```
   for row in lis:
        csv_out.writerow(flatten_row(row))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at @jagadeesh mn as it looks more generalizable. My answer is extremely dependent on the positioning which is not extendable. However, I am posting a quick and dirty code to flatten.

```
test=[('bba', [('happy:units:1', 'cloud:1'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:2'), 'rating:3']),('bcc', [('happy:units:2', 'cloud:2'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:3'), 'rating:5'])]
col_id=[];
col_rating=[];
col_happy=[];
col_cloud=[];
col_sad=[];
col_rain=[];

for row in test:
    col_id.append(row[0])
    for j,row2 in enumerate(row[1]):
        if(j==2):
            col_rating.append(row2[row2.rfind(':')+1:])
        if(j==0):
            for k,row3 in enumerate(row2):
                if(k==0):
                    col_happy.append(row3[row3.rfind(':')+1:])
                if(k==1):
                    col_cloud.append(row3[row3.rfind(':')+1:])
        if(j==1):
            for k,row3 in enumerate(row2):
                if(k==0):
                    col_sad.append(row3[row3.rfind(':')+1:])
                if(k==1):
                    col_rain.append(row3[row3.rfind(':')+1:])


final_list = list(zip(col_id,col_rating,col_happy,col_cloud,col_sad,col_rain))
```

Answer (score -1):

A less error prone solution:

```
li = [('a', [('happy:units:1', 'cloud:1'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:2'), 'rating:3']),]

li = list(li[0])

li = [li[0]] + li[1]

def flatten_row(inp_lst):
    ou = []
    for x in inp_lst:
        if isinstance(x, basestring):
            ou.append(x)
        else:
            ou += list(x)
    return ou

def get_values(inp_lst):
    ou = []
    for el in inp_lst:
        pos = el.rfind(":") + 1
        ou.append(el[pos:])
    return ou

with open(output_file, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([['id', 'happy:units', 'cloud', 'sad:units', 'rain', 'rating'], 
    get_values(flatten_row(li))])
```

Answer (score -1):

As long as your input list is intact to the pattern you have mentioned in question, below code will work. I have put the items in list, and you can convert them into csv the way you would like. Try it out.

```
lis = [('a', [('happy:units:1', 'cloud:1'), ('sad:units:1', 'rain:2'), 'rating:3']),]
res = list()
for i in xrange(0,len(lis[len(lis)-1])):
        if len(lis[0][i]) > 0:
                for j in xrange(0,len(lis[0][i])):
                        if len(lis[0][i][j]) >= 1 and type(lis[0][i][j]) == tuple:
                                for x in xrange(0,len(lis[0][i][j])):
                                        res.append(lis[0][i][j][x])
                        else:
                                res.append(lis[0][i][j])
csv = list()
csv.append(res[0])
for i in xrange(1,len(res)):
        csv.append(res[i][:-2]+'='+res[i][len(res[i])-1:])
print("Output: {}".format(csv))
```

OutPut:

```
['a', 'happy:units=1', 'cloud=1', 'sad:units=1', 'rain=2', 'rating=3']
```